# What to return from service "onStartCommand" if code determines that you shouldn't start ther service?

Tags: java, android, android-service

I have a service which sends values from the user over HTTP post to a server.

One of the things I want from onStartCommand is to confirm all the necessary data has been added to the sharedPreferences, and not run the service if it hasn't.

Checking and alerting the user is easy enough, however what should onStartCommand return if decided not to run the service?
Currently I am returning start_not_sticky and then killing the service.
Is there are "not_start" or similar return value?

Comment: Why not just check the SharedPreferences outside of the Service code, and if they are not there, don't call startService()?

Comment: @Daniel This is being checked on button press. However is going to be reused as there is a number of places this service is likely to be used. The project is not only being developed by myself, but also others inside and outside of my team. I think it is important to develop modular code that can work independent of checks done prior to calling. I have always found it safest to reiterate checks inside code. Of course if that is the only option available I will have to accept only checking prior to startService();

Comment: I had faced the same question a while ago - found no other way than stopping and killing (stop alone is not enough - kill is required for some rare cases)